# 7zip Extraction and Delete Fail on only one of many files

Tags: php, recursion, cmd, 7zip, extract

I tried using PHP to run 7zip to recursively extract all the zip files that a user had put inside other zip files and then delete the original zip.

The code I used worked except for a larger file (about 7gigs) that had some unusual file types (like hdr and cab files for example) where it did not fully extract the files, made duplicates of some of the ones it did, and then did not delete the original zip. The only thing I saw out of the ordinary about it was that the command prompt I ran the php file from said "Incomplete Extraction". I'm not sure why the extraction and deletion worked for every file but this one.

Any help in understanding this would be greatly appreciated! 
Thank you for your time

Here is the code snippet:

```
$cmd_2 = "FOR /R \"$zip_file_directory\" %I IN (*.zip) DO (7z x \"%I\" -aou -o\"%~dpI\" && del \"%~fI\")";
exec($cmd_2, $out_2, $ret_2);
```

**EDIT**

Also it returned a 0 exit code. So again I have no idea what went wrong.
However looking at the `$out` I can see about 2700 key/value relationships in the array (Example: `[2685] => Extracting Client Video\Reviewer\setup.lid`)
And at the very end it says "Sub Item Errors: 5" but I can't seem to find a way to find exactly what that means.

**EDIT II**
I was going through the 2700 lines of code and found a few like this: "`[1325] => can not open output file` ...." and then has a filename. 
Any idea why this is happening so rarely (It looks like these are the 5 errors) out of thousands of lines of extraction?

**EDIT III**

There is an article [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45798/thread/fd267533/) that states that this might be a 7zip issue with firewall, can anyone confirm or deny this?

Comment: did you check the exit code ? http://7zip.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/exit_codes.htm

Comment: let's starting by this : extraction of a larger file > 7gigs failed. What happened when you extract it using command line ?

Comment: @willl It returned a 0 code